# Adding worksheet_Change in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How should I go about adding a worksheet_change subroutine in another workbook? I have a daily job run which pick up file from the server, open it, do some formatting change, and then pass it back to the end users to work on it. One of the formatting change I need to do to the file is to create dependent drop down list through data validation.

Supposedly I have two fields, "Main_Category" and "Sub_Category", I want to be able to let end users to make their selections based on a standardized drop down list. Once users made their selection for "Main_Category", the drop down list for "Sub_Category" will be populated based on the "Main_Category". My dilemma is that if the users changed their mind on the "Main_Category" after selecting "Sub_Category", excel will not clear this selection..

My thought is to add a worksheet_change to the file. But how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the exact point of your question, but hope this helps.

**To identify changes on a worksheet, you may use two main methods:**

- [SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx) - Occurs when the selection changes on a
  worksheet
- [Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) - Occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the
  user or by an external link

You may find how to use the same on the links above. Basically you will need to add the corresponding method to the sheet on which you want to track changes (you may do this by selecting the sheet code on VBE and typing the code there), then use the Target parameter to get more information about the change which occurred and executed the required code (for example to clear or update the value of some range).

This will work fine, considering that you add the code to each workbook/worksheets on which you need it.

**Add code programatically to a workbook:**

If you would like to programatically add this code to new workbooks, you will need to Trust access to the VBA project object model, as described on:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/282830.
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt6cbe57.aspx

Still, ***please notice that this is not recommended from a security perspective***, as this will allow other programs to change, replicate and run any code inside excel. If you really need this, an options is to manually change this option before running a macro and then change it back again.